# use lapply and plot to draw multiple plots

Tags: r

try to run the following code, but always got error message:

> Error in text.default(x, y, txt, cex = cex, font = font) : invalid
>   mathematical annotation

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
x <- c(1:4,6:9)
myPlot<-function(x){
    plot(pros.dat, pros.dat$svi ~ pros.dat[,x])
}
lapply(c(1:4,6:9), FUN=myPlot)
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you try just change to `plot(data = pros.dat, svi ~ pros.dat[,x])` inside your myPlot function?

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed. I got the same error message.

Comment: This works on `mtcars` data set. `x <- c(1:4,6:9)
myPlot<-function(x){
  plot(data = mtcars, mpg ~ mtcars[,x])
}
lapply(c(1:4,6:9), FUN=myPlot)`

Answer (score 0):

R's plot function's definition is:

```
plot(x, y, ...)
```

So you should define your function as:

```
myPlot<-function(x){
    plot(pros.dat$svi, pros.dat[,x])
}
```

Comment: OP could  do that, but there is also a `plot.formula` function, which gets called, when you do something like plot(data = mtcars, mpg ~ wt)

Comment: Yes, to add here, if you want to use plot.formula, you need to give column names instead of slice column by position